# Проблема с наложением фона на определенный участок

Tags: css3, html5

Как убрать эти белые участки?

[image]

```css
.fon_shapki {
    background-color: #445162;
}
shapka {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 51px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.info {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html">
        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fon_shapki">
            <div class="shapka">
                Product name
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <li>Put on this page informatiom about your product</li>
                <li>A detailed descroption of your ptoduct</li>
                <li>Tell us about the advantages and merits</li>
                <li>Associate the page with the payment system</li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            About yout product
        </div>
        <div class="opisanie">
            <p>Loram ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nodis facilis fuga, illo at. Natus eos,
            <br>elegendi illum rerum omnis porro exm magni, explicabo vaniam incidunt in quam sapiente ut
            <br>ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Текст что ли?))

Comment: Подробнее - какие участки?

Comment: Вот эти участки http://prntscr.com/n306j3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду отступы от рамки окна браузера,
добавьте reset CSS стандартных настроек браузера (в самое начало кода CSS).

Например:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: А с этим что делать? http://prntscr.com/n30hd1

Comment: Это, видимо, отступ margin-top. Margin отвечает за внешние отступы, и на них не действует фон элемента и другие стили. Padding отвечает за внутренние отступы. Попробуйте поменять свойства. И добавьте, пожалуйста, обновленный код если не разберетесь.

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо большое!